# Need help for advanced level grouping and data manipulation in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have the following data set:

```
Employee    EducLev JobGrade    YrsExper    Age Gender  YrsPrior    PCJob   Salary
1   3   1   3   26  Male    1   No  32000
2   1   1   14  38  Female  1   No  39100
3   1   1   12  35  Female  0   No  33200
4   2   1   8   40  Female  7   No  30600
5   3   1   3   28  Male    0   No  29000
6   3   2   3   24  Female  0   No  30500
7   3   2   4   27  Female  0   No  30000
8   3   2   8   33  Male    2   No  27000
9   1   3   4   62  Female  0   No  34000
10  3   3   9   31  Female  0   No  29500
11  3   4   9   34  Female  2   No  26800
12  2   5   8   37  Female  8   No  31300
13  2   5   9   37  Female  0   No  31200
14  2   6   10  58  Female  6   No  34700
15  3   6   4   33  Female  0   No  30000
16  3   6   3   27  Female  0   No  31000
```

And I need an output like this:

```
JobGrade    Female  Male    Total
1            34.29% 17.65%  28.85%
2            20.71% 19.12%  20.19%
3            25.71% 10.29%  20.67%
4            12.14% 16.18%  13.46%
5            6.43%  17.65%  10.10%
6            0.71%  19.12%  6.73%
```

I have looked at some other posts which use the aggregate function. I am not able to use it in this context. Can anyone help me on how to get an output like this?
P.S: I don't want to do this by calculating all the percentages and then creating a new data set.

I had used the following code to solve the question myself. But I don't think this is the right way to solve this problem.

```
df = data.frame(jobgrade=numeric(), gmale=numeric(), gfemale=numeric(), total=numeric())

for(i in 1:6)
{
 df[i,]=c(i, nrow(bsal[bsal$Gender=="Male"&bsal$JobGrade==i,]) * 100 / nrow(bsal[bsal$JobGrade==i,]), 
          nrow(bsal[bsal$Gender=="Female"& bsal$JobGrade==i,]) * 100 / nrow(bsal[bsal$JobGrade==i,]),
          nrow(bsal[bsal$JobGrade==i,]) * 100/nrow(bsal))
}
```

Comment: Please read the info on how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Hey, thanks for editing my post. I was trying to figure out how to do the proper formatting

Comment: np, now you know how to ;-)

Comment: Try writing some code and if you encounter a problem, ask a question, including the code in the description. As you say, try the method using the aggregate function and then ask a question about the problem you'd encounter in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `aggregate`. Let's say your data.frame is named df. This method first creates a column that is filled ones, I named it dumm below. You could avoid this step and perform it afterward.

```
df$dumm <- 1
results <- aggregate(cbind("Female"=df$Gender == "Female", 
                           "Male"=df$Gender == "Male",
                           "total"=df$dumm), 
                    by=list(df$JobGrade), fun=sum)
```

The results data.frame has the count of males, females, and total by job grade. Now just divide by the sum of total:

```
results <- results / sum(results$total)
```

---

A second method that is pretty common is with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

results <- df[, list("Female"=sum(Gender == "Female"), 
                               "Male"=sum(Gender == "Male"),
                               "total"=length(Gender)), 
              by=.(JobGrade)]
results <- df[, lapply(.SD, function(i) i / sum(total)), .SDcols=2:4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting the number of males and females in the data set now. I can get the percentages by dividing all values by total. Could you please explain what you did using df$dumm?

Comment: I added some points to my answer, hopefully, these will be helpful.

Comment: Yes got it now. Thanks. I had used a very crude method to do it myself which I have included in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `data.table` with `dcast`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), convert to 'wide' format specifying the `fun.aggregate` as `length`,  `join` with the summarized count by 'JobGrade' dataset `on` 'JobGrade', assign (`:=`) the columns 2:4 to the output obtained by dividing with the `sum` of 'Total'.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), JobGrade~Gender, value.var= "Gender", length)[df1[
  , .(Total=.N) ,.(JobGrade)], on = "JobGrade"][, (2:4) := lapply(.SD, `/`, 
             sum(Total)), .SDcols = 2:4][]
```

---

This could be also done using `base R` compact options

```
t1 <- addmargins(table(df1[c("JobGrade", "Gender")]), 2)
t1/sum(t1[,'Sum'])
```